# Converting HTML to sentences

Tags: java, html, text

I was wondering if there was a way to convert HTML to sentences, for example, using JSoup. What I am looking for is something like:

```
List<String> convertToSentences(String html);
```

Sometimes sentences are separated by dots, question and exclamation marks, and sometimes by HTML structures, like `<ul>`'s and `<p>`'s

For example, given the following HTML:

```
<p>Hello World. What a great day.</p>    // [Hello world, What a great day]
<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li></ul>        // [One, Two]
<p>Today is <strong>great</great></p>    // [Today is great]
```

Is there any library out there which does such a thing?